# Image color not changing in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-container

following is my code for changing image color. I selected the image color to yellow from color picker after inserting the cs script to my image properties an assigned the yellow color from color picker to the field of color of image.

```
public Color normalColor;
public Color selectedColor;
public Image image;

public void Select(){
    isSelected = !isSelected;
    image.color = isSelected ? selectedColor : normalColor;

    if (isSelected) {
        WordScramble.main.Select (this);
    } else {
        WordScramble.main.UnSelect(this);
    }

}
```

The Select function is called on clicking the image, and it is correctly calling and working its functionality except the changing of color. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: what is `image`? where is it declared? usually you will need to change an objects material, or the color of the light hitting it to change an objects color.

Comment: @Vanethrane i edited the code. I missed it in posting here.

Comment: @SurrayaMarvi I tested your code and it works fine. Do you set any `Animation` to your `Image`? Or does the `Image` game object have `Animator` component?

Answer (score 0):

`image.GetComponent<Image>().color = isSelected ? selectedColor : normalColor;`

gotta get the image not just the gameobject. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test07a : MonoBehaviour {
    public Color normalColor;
    public Color selectedColor;
    public Image image;
    private bool isSelected;

    public void Select(){
        isSelected = !isSelected;
        image.color = isSelected ? selectedColor : normalColor;

        if (isSelected) {
            Debug.Log ("selected");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("not selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Tried that code and worked fine (I removed `WordScramble` and initialize bool `isSelected` for experimental purpose).
If your problem is the image disappear when it is clicked, try to check the alpha of the color from your color picker :
[that's the problem when I try your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drOfj.png)